# InnoDB Cluster - addInstance have issue. what is the step for troubleshoot

Tags: innodb

cluster.addInstance("root@c-1:3306");
A new instance will be added to the InnoDB cluster. Depending on the amount of
data on the cluster this might take from a few seconds to several hours.

Adding instance to the cluster ...

Validating instance at c-1:3306...

This instance reports its own address as c-1

Instance configuration is suitable.

Cluster.addInstance: WARNING: Not running locally on the server and can not access its error log.
ERROR:
Group Replication join failed.
ERROR: Error joining instance to cluster: 'c-1:3306' - Query failed. MySQL Error (3092): ClassicSession.query: The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log.. Query: START group_replication: MySQL Error (3092): ClassicSession.query: The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log. (RuntimeError)

=======================

## Below are the log:

2019-06-06T12:46:51.133928Z 12 [ERROR] [MY-011685] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'The group name option is mandatory'
2019-06-06T12:46:51.133965Z 12 [ERROR] [MY-011660] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Unable to start Group Replication on boot'
2019-06-06T12:46:56.214339Z 12 [Warning] [MY-010604] [Repl] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=mysql-3-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2019-06-06T12:46:56.227192Z 12 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2019-06-06T12:46:56.269388Z 14 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_applier' executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2019-06-06T12:47:06.366876Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:47:16.377672Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:47:26.388546Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:47:36.399292Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:47:46.410106Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:47:56.295865Z 12 [ERROR] [MY-011640] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Timeout on wait for view after joining group'
2019-06-06T12:47:56.296117Z 12 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member is already leaving or joining a group.'
2019-06-06T12:47:56.416640Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:48:06.427452Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:48:16.438305Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:48:26.449166Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:48:36.450212Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2019-06-06T12:48:36.450316Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error connecting to all peers. Member join failed. Local port: 33061'
2019-06-06T12:48:36.475141Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'

Comment: Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed.... is this the problem?

Comment: group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to c-1:33061 on local port: 33061... look like its port issue. 33061 must be open bi directional???

Comment: did you fix this issue? I have the same problem.